# Stuck with two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a booking service and I've been stuck on this part for many hours and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

So I've got a Two Dimensional array and when trying to print out some stuff when testing and trying to figure out what's wrong, all I get is `System.String[]` which doesn't really make me any wiser. I want to be able to access the details in i.e. `m_nameMatrix[0,0]` to check whether the seat is reserved or not.

Here's a snippet from my form code:

```
private void UpdateGUI(string customerName, double price)
{
    string selectedItem = cmdDisplayOptions.Items[cmdDisplayOptions.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    rbtnReserve.Checked = true;
    lstSeats.Items.Clear();
    lstSeats.Items.AddRange(m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(selectedItem));
}
```

And here are two methods from my 2nd class:

```
public string[] GetSeatInfoStrings(string selectedItem)
{
    int count = GetNumOfSeats(selectedItem);

    if (count <= 0)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
    string[] strSeatInfoStrings = new string[count];

    for (int index = 0; index <= count; index++)
    {
        strSeatInfoStrings[index] = GetSeatInfoAt(index);
    }
    return strSeatInfoStrings;
}

public string GetSeatInfoAt(int index)
{
    int row = (int)Math.Floor((double)(index / m_totNumOfCols));
    int col = index % m_totNumOfCols;

    string seatInfo = m_nameMatrix.GetValue(row, col).ToString();
    return seatInfo;
}
```

I'm not actually getting an exception so it might be my logical thinking that's been taking a hit due to hours and hours of trying to figure it out.

EDIT:

```
public void ReserveSeat(string name, double price, int index)
    {
        int row = (int)Math.Floor((double)(index / m_totNumOfCols));
        int col = index % m_totNumOfCols;

        string reserved = string.Format("{0,3} {1,3} {2, 8} {3, 8} {4,22:f2}",
                                        row + 1, col + 1, "Reserved", name, price);

        m_nameMatrix[row, col] = reserved;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't solve anything. Thanks though.

Comment: @GrantWinney I've tried printing it out in a MessageBox.Show and that's when I get it.

Comment: Step through the debugger and check your values after each statement. What is cmdDisplayOptions? If the objects contained in the Items array of that variable do not have a ToString() method, then this could be the source of your problem. Either way, use the debugger to figure out which line is causing the problem and let us know.

Comment: @DanielSimpkins I will try that, thanks. By the way, cmdDisplayOptions is supposed to be a combobox where the user can change whether to see all seats, only the available ones or all the taken ones.

Comment: @GrantWinney Oh, I'm really new to C#, so thanks for telling me. In my experience, limited as it may be, when programming I like to test very often what is contained within variables and so forth. How can I check what is contained within a certain position in a 2D array in C#?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
for (int index = 0; index <= count; index++)
```

should be:

```
for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
```

Why? Lets say I have an array with 2 objects in it. `count` would be 2. *However*, the indexes are *0* and *1*. So you have to use a *less than* operator.

Comment: He's most likely gonna mark everything as wrong even if they're right because he gets the exception from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting "`System.String[]`" in your messagebox, it's because you're trying to print a `string[]` directly, rather than the various strings it contains:

```
string[] data = GetSeatInfoStrings("foo");
MessageBox.Show(data);
```

Instead, you need to show the *contents* of data:

```
string[] data = GetSeatInfoStrings("foo");
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", data));
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) for the documentation.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying that now. Now I got stuck on this row in the code with the debugger `string seatInfo = m_nameMatrix.GetValue(row, col).ToString();` with the error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Erik - That means that either `m_nameMatrix` is `null`, or that `GetValue(row, col)` is returning null.  Probably the first one, since you don't show that code.

Comment: You may very well be right. I'll put the code up in the original post if you don't mind having a quick look. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I tried `m_nameMatrix.GetValue(row,col) == null` and found out that was true while m_nameMatrix wasn't null. So I guess that's established at least.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a method called `ReturnArray()`:

```
class Class2
    {
        public string[] ReturnArray()
        {
            string[] str = new string[] { "hello", "hi" };
            return str;
        }

    }
```

If you called `ReturnArray` in your main class like this:

```
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(class2.ReturnArray());
    }
```

it will return `System.String[]` because [`MessageBox.Show(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) takes a `string` as an argument, in this case.

So you'll also get the same result by using `MessageBox.Show(class2.ReturnArray().ToString());`

Instead, you may want to do something like this:

```
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] strArray = class2.ReturnArray();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(strArray);
    }
```